# Type inference fails if using a separate file to consume function

Tags: typescript

I have a little helper to extract an instance from a config object using a `getService('name')` method. It works fine if the consuming code is in the same file, but when I use a test file, TS loses inference. Here are my tsconfigs for the project:
tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "include": [],
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.lib.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.lib.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["./src/**/*.test.ts", "./src/**/*.test.tsx"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.tsx"]
}
```

tsconfig.node.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.tsx"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.test.ts", "./src/**/*.test.tsx"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "types": ["node", "jest"]
  }
}
```

Compiler options for the root config are:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"target": "ESNext",
"useDefineForClassFields": true,
"lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
"allowJs": false,
"skipLibCheck": true,
"esModuleInterop": false,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"strict": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"module": "ESNext",
"moduleResolution": "Node",
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"isolatedModules": true,
"noEmit": true,
"jsx": "react-jsx"
```

The code in question is here: [Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSA7AVsAxjAQwCMAbYAHgBU4BeOAjRAGjgBFgwBnOUGYDACbdMOfMTLkGiAHwBtALq04C6UoDeAKDhwBHAMIALAgEsMALnTY8hUsAUBuLTo79dGXMeCcLsgHT%20Ra3E7eXlHbQBzYBgLAAoAd2MYA3YuAH4LIggIMgYASlpVAAUoCABbY04KSmlwuCiYTE5Cd2A4gppVagAfOABXQWAAM1NgATrjMshYADFzOABBTkR3GYJ8aEQ5qhZUzlqnU2aGXGAMuEoJzgAlLxyAN1MI2LzM7NyMOqMbu5J7sZebxywAYdQgGHYzVKiDiRxapwslA6qnuEGM4w0AF9HBpQNN4EgUItlqt1jBNttKLsONxeK5uFIFEpGfJVHRYk5-L4CFAIt44JptNpZABpOCmOAAa2AiAgQzYNPkFj2osUdMEwisYls5FMQ2AUDgAFVVGljXALBhgP8oHVMRpkXASuVKtUDrjwNACchUABREAwKBkprwt1KajqoSWUQ2CR6g3G03my3Wg043Dg5pwMqIQLasjqTH0TUx4LkNRwTjlYAANQIJD6bQQUEbcEx7ozGCznZGEXUThzedjwCYWJxeK9cCGA3wxnBcAMIIEZE4nBeAqcUGifSgGA3Qvq0QAygbHqdR9psRonAQSbgpzOYHO9w0T1Az9UeAH6VKZXKED6-49sYETSLE0owhcBSCkKnZZlunCQF2qB0AQ8QmPAwERLIEHyL4DQvDiB5bjAO57ghSFVMWcD%20oGwZdqG5CxISwBAeCvZ5LIlCsnaWLXixcAABJLiu3B0LcpG7pQPrkCx-6LgQy5ePs6aZvABBgGASgKUpq7rreQkicpqkMdmiBvh%20zKafhx6nsYpyxAA5IOWrDo5eT2EAA)

If I move the bottom two lines into a test file, I get `myService` inferred as `any`.

Comment: Please put a [mre] **in the question**.

Comment: I've been unable to create an MRE. To be honest, I think that if I could produce that, then the issue would have been solved already.